# Добавить кнопку в expander

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть макет(скорее всего во много неправильный, но это лабораторная с упором на бэк, это я пытаюсь что-то визуально приятное сделать, не заморачиваясь над правильностью, потому что времени не так много), в котором есть `expander` в котором есть кнопка, но мне нужно количество кнопок >=2, как добавить еще одну?
На всякий случай прикрепляю полный код:

```
<Window x:Class="TimeTrees.DesktopGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeTrees.DesktopGUI"
        xmlns:svgc="http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/svgc/"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Background="#2b3825" Height="20" FontWeight="Bold" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        </DockPanel>

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="38"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="327*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="327*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="59*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Image Source="Images/timetrees.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#4f7344">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Expander Margin="5" Header="Функции" Padding="5" BorderBrush="#b1c3b8" BorderThickness="0">
                        <Button Margin="5" Height="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{svgc:SvgImage Source=/Images/user-add-fill.svg, AppName = TimeTrees.Desktop}" Stretch="Fill" Width="25" Height="25" />
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Add</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </Expander>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="#b1c3b8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        <StatusBar Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Background="#2b3825">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Label x:Name="lblCurrentState" Content="State" FontWeight="Normal"></Label>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Label x:Name="lblCoordinates" Content="Coordinates" FontWeight="Normal"></Label>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <Label x:Name="lblIsHover" Content="Hover" FontWeight="Normal"></Label>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вот так выглядит макет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под `Add` должна быть кнопка еще одна.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/IlyaKvashnin/TimeTrees/-/tree/lab3-GUI
Если вдруг надо будет запустить, вот код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Expander>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

Comment: полезно будет почитать - https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.4.php

Comment: `XAML0501: Свойство "Content" установлено больше одного раза` когда добавляю кнопку, вот по вашей схеме

Comment: Могу выложить код с двумя кнопками, да, я как раз на метаните и читал, не понимаю почему ошибку эту выдает. Оборачивал в `grid`, но тогда получаю кнопку на кнопке

Comment: Я не знаю так важно ли это, но в кнопке у меня `stackpanel`, чтобы поместить иконку с текстом

Comment: Я сделал еще одну вложенную `stackpanel`, спасибо!